# std::trunc not available on Android?

Tags: android, c++11, android-ndk, cmath

Using C++'s `std::trunc` in `android` errors out saying `trunc is not a member of std`

**Is there an alternative or a work around ?** 
`<cmath>` is included in my code.

My environment is:

```
NDK Version is r13b
ANDROID_NDK_PLATFORM = 23
ANDROID_NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION = 4.9
```

Comment: Which STL implemetation are you using?

Comment: the one that C++11 provides. Not sure what exactly is your question here

Comment: https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpp-support.html

Comment: @SegmentationFault C++11 is a standard, not an implementation of the standard library.

Comment: my mistake. its `gnustl_static` I am using. `std::trunc` doesn't seem to be available. I figured a different approach of truncating digits after decimal point which I needed.. something like `(((unsigned int) index*100) % 100)/100`. Yeah